# sum in mysql 2 table with condtion

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Sql Query One will Give The Installments Not Paid By Clients And The Other Search In date And show The Installment Not Paid By All Clients I would Like To Try Show The Installments Not paid In the second Query So his the first Sql:

```
        SELECT tbl_Clients.IDcli,
     tbl_Clients.cname, installments.InstallmentID, 
 installments.Number_install, 
 Sum(Installment_part.State) AS SumOfState 
 FROM (tbl_paystatus INNER JOIN 
 (tbl_Clients INNER JOIN 
 (installments INNER JOIN
 Installment_part ON 
 installments.InstallmentID = Installment_part.InstallmentID)
 ON tbl_Clients.IDcli = installments.ClientID)
 ON tbl_paystatus.ID = Installment_part.State)
 INNER JOIN items_co ON
 installments.Device_ID = items_co.ItemID 
 GROUP BY tbl_Clients.IDcli, tbl_Clients.cname,
 items_co.ItemName, installments.InstallmentID,
 installments.Title, installments.Install_date, 
 installments.Total_Value, installments.Number_install,
 Installment_part.Part_value 
 HAVING (((tbl_Clients.cname)='SomeClinentName'));
```

And The Result For this Query IS :

```
[
    {
        "IDcli" : 114,
        "cname" : SomeClientName,
        "InstallmentID" : 96,
        "Number_install" : 4,
        "SumOfState" : 3
    }
]
```

The Second Query :

```
SELECT tbl_Clients.cname,
 Installment_part.Due_date,
 Installment_part.Part_value,
 tbl_paystatus.paymenttext, 
 tbl_Clients.cphone, 
 tbl_Clients.cphone2,
 tbl_company.Compnyname,

 Installment_part.Parts_ID, 
 tbl_Clients.IDcli,
  installments.Number_install
 FROM tbl_paystatus
 INNER JOIN
 (tbl_company INNER JOIN 
 (tbl_Clients INNER JOIN
 (installments INNER JOIN 
 Installment_part 
 ON 
 installments.InstallmentID = Installment_part.InstallmentID)
 ON tbl_Clients.IDcli = installments.ClientID) ON
 tbl_company.idcop = tbl_Clients.comId) ON 
 tbl_paystatus.ID = Installment_part.State 
 WHERE (Installment_part.Due_date>='2016-01-01')
 And (Installment_part.Due_date<='2016-06-30') 
 and Installment_part.State=0;
```

i want To show  (Sum(Installment_part.State) AS SumOfState ) But when I put In the First Query It only Show me One row and in this Query I have 459 Row.

The Sample Result :

```
cname,Due_date,Part_value,paymenttext,cphone,cphone2,Compnyname,Parts_ID,IDcli,Number_install
"clinet1","2016-05-01 00:00:00",375,"Notpaid",0912267416,0000,"Privte",244,70,4
"clinet1","2016-06-01 00:00:00",375,"Notpaid",0912267416,0000,"Privte",245,70,4
"clinet2","2016-06-30 00:00:00",750,"Notpaid",0912996312,000,Privte,328,90,4
"clinet2","2016-06-30 00:00:00",1250,"Notpaid",0912996312,0000,Privte,332,91,4
"clinet4","2016-06-28 00:00:00",550,"Notpaid",0922223174,0912678557,Privte,387,108,4
"clinet5","2016-06-30 00:00:00",550,"Notpaid",0964646960,0000,"Privte",391,110,4
"clinet6","2016-06-30 00:00:00",950,"Notpaid",0115909916,000,"Privte",395,111,4
"clinet7","2016-06-30 00:00:00",700,"Notpaid",0908000272,0000,"Privte",407,114,4
"clinet8","2016-06-30 00:00:00",2250,"Notpaid",0917171723,0122097988,"Privte",411,115,4
"clinet9","2016-06-30 00:00:00",550,"Notpaid",0999454466,0000,"Privte",427,119,4
"clinet10","2016-06-29 00:00:00",375,"Notpaid",0912618156,0112939782,Privte,439,125,4
"clinet11","2016-06-24 00:00:00",550,"Notpaid",0809911715,0902838483,"Privte",447,127,4
"clinet12","2016-03-26 00:00:00",550,"Notpaid",0911119122,0000,"Privte",452,130,4
```

Comment: The 2nd query does not have a `group by` clause, therefore the use of any aggregation function (such as sum()) will cause MySQL to collapse the resultset into a single line.

Comment: If I add Group By It will Collect All The Client Name In one Row

Comment: I will Add the Sample Query Result  To Understand It in better way .

Comment: 1) You do not have to start all words with a capital letter. 2) Add an **appropriate** group by clause to your query.

Comment: Can You Show To Me what Do You mean

Comment: I cannot show you anything because you have not provided any information on what the expected results should look like.